# iPads on Business account need to group message

Tags: group

I have 10 iPads that we use for training.  I want to be able to text as a group as we are working on activities.  How do I set up the iPads to allow group messaging without facebook or phone numbers?  They all have the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the same Apple ID to login to all the iPad, how will you identify *who* sent *which* message?

If the identity of sender and recipient are irrelevant, and you just need the message to be synced across all the iPads, an inelegant but simple approach is to send the message to yourself, i.e. the same Apple ID which is logged into iPad.

The downsides will be that the each message will appear *twice*, once for sender and once for receiver. Also, the message will be marked as read **immediately**.

The solution discussed above is not elegant and it is recommended that you register each iPad with unique Apple ID, and create an iMessage group conversation with all the recipients added.